# I cannot display a specific form field to the user after validation fails using jquery

Tags: php, jquery

I need some help. The alert message that pops-up when a user submits the form below and validation fails does not display first name required. It only displays last name required but when i fill out the last name and submit then it displays first name required. What do i need to do to make them both appear on the alert. Code is below

this is form.php code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=yes">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>

  <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light navbar-fixed-top">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">MIT Moonlight Sail</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="moonlightsail.html">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="http://example.com" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Reservations</a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="newreservation_OOP.php">Make a reservation</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Modify a reservation</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Cancel a reservation</a>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>


<div class="card">
    <div class="card-body">
      <p>Welcome to Moonlight Sailing at the <a href="https://sailing.mit.edu" target="_blank">MIT Sailing Pavilion</a>.<br />
    By making a reservation, or using the boats or facilities, you agree to abide by the 
    <a href="https://sailing.mit.edu/info/rules.php" target="_blank">general rules of the MIT Sailing Pavilion</a> and the specific rules of the moonlight sailing available.</p>

  <p><span style="font-weight:bold">Your group may only have one active reservation at a time.</span>  "Active" means waiting waiting to sail or sailing on a boat.  Once you delete your reservation or return from your sail you may make another reservation.</p> 

  <p>To accommodate as many people as possible, we may combine groups and take groups out of order so as to have full boats.</p>
  <p>Enter your reservation details below.<br />

  Upon submission you wil be issued a unique ID number that you can use to update or delete your reservation.<br /></p>


    <form role="form" id="contactForm" class="contact-form" data-toggle="validator" class="shake">
      <div class="alert alert-danger  display-error alert-dismissable"   role="alert" style="display: none"> 
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>  
        </button>
      </div>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fname" placeholder="First Name">
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lname" placeholder="Last Name">
        </div>
      </div>


      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="controls">
          <input type="email" class="email form-control"  id="email"   placeholder="Email" >
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="controls">
          <input type="text" id="msg_subject" class="form-control" placeholder="Subject" >
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="controls">
          <textarea id="message" rows="7" placeholder="Message" class="form-control"></textarea>
        </div>  
      </div>
      <button type="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-success"><i class="fa fa-check"></i> Submit Reservation</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>




          <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
          <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
          <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
          <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
          <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
          <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>

          <script type="text/javascript">
          $(document).ready(function() {

            $('#submit').click(function(e) {
              e.preventDefault();

              var fname = $("#fname").val();
              var lname = $("#lname").val();
              var email = $("#email").val();
              var msg_subject = $("#msg_subject").val();
              var message = $("#message").val();


              $.ajax({
                  type: "POST",
                  url: "myformprocess.php",
                  dataType: "json",
                  data: {fname:fname, lname:lname, email:email, msg_subject:msg_subject, message:message},

                  success : function(data){
                      if (data.code == "200"){
                          alert("Success: "+data.msg);

                      } else {

                          $(".display-error").html("<ul>"+data.msg+"</ul>");
                          $(".display-error").css("display","block");

                      }
                  }
              });
            });
        });
      </script>   
  </body>
</html>
```

This is the PHP validation

```
<?php

 $errorMSG = "";

/* First NAME */

if (empty($_POST["fname"])) {

$errorMSG = "<li>First Name is required</<li>";

} else {

$fname = $_POST["fname"];

}


/* Last Name */

 if (empty($_POST["lname"])) {

$errorMSG = "<li>Last Name is required</<li>";

} else {

$lname = $_POST["lname"];

} 

/* EMAIL */

if (empty($_POST["email"])) {

$errorMSG .= "<li>Email is required</li>";

} else if(!filter_var($_POST["email"], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {



 $errorMSG .= "<li>Invalid email format</li>";

   }else {

    $email = $_POST["email"];

    }



/* MSG SUBJECT */

   if (empty($_POST["msg_subject"])) {

    $errorMSG .= "<li>Subject is required</li>";

   } else {

    $msg_subject = $_POST["msg_subject"];



}


    /* MESSAGE */

    if (empty($_POST["message"])) {

    $errorMSG .= "<li>Message is required</li>";



} else {

  $message = $_POST["message"];

  }


 if(empty($errorMSG)){
$msg = "First Name: ".$fname. ",Last Name: ".$lname. ", Email: 
".$email.", Subject: ".$msg_subject.", Message:".$message;

echo json_encode(['code'=>200, 'msg'=>$msg]);

exit;

}




echo json_encode(['code'=>404, 'msg'=>$errorMSG]);


  ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change this:

```
$errorMSG = "<li>Last Name is required</<li>";
```

to this:

```
$errorMSG .= "<li>Last Name is required</<li>";
```

You've overwriting the change you make with the first name and need to [concatenate](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php) it instead.

Answer (score 0):

Note the difference in your code between:

```
$errorMSG .= "<li>Email is required</li>";
```

and

```
$errorMSG = "<li>Last Name is required</<li>";
```

You need to append, not replace the error message. The "dot equals" is used to append to the var:

```
 $errorMSG .= "<li>Last Name is required</<li>";
```